# Confusion exercise -use the type right

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, poisson-distribution

From a research is known that average 1% of drivers are causing a car accident every year.One safe company has 1000 drivers that are been on them.What is the possibility that the company should pay for more than 2 accidents of their customers in the next year. What i did , i thought i have 1% on average so to find

```
λ =0.01 *1000=10 so i have λ

    f(x)=e^-λ * λ^x/x!= e^-10 * 10^2/2!
```

I have done Poisson ,am i right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s binomial with $n=1000$ and $p=0.01$. Furthermore, you have to calculate $P(X>2)$.

Comment: nope its poison cause it says average and it has and time inside

Comment: So if you’re already know all of the the exercise: why are you posing a question at all?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe i don't know if my way is right..i mean if i solve right the poisson

Answer (score 1):

As 
$$X=\text{number of accidents per year}$$
 is bounded by $1000$ we can't have a Poisson here at all, strictly speaking.  Definitely $X$ is binomial with $n=1000$ and $p=0.01$. The task ist to calculate 
$$P(X>2)=1-P(X\leq2)=0.997320568006$$
via binomial distribution.

As $p$ is small, one may approximate the binomial distribution by a Poisson.  In this case 
$$P(X>2)=1-P(X\leq2)=0.997320604284$$
via Poisson.